# Mysql trigger for all table

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

is that possible to create a mysql trigger for all table in a database?

I have look for a several example to using trigger to spesific table in a database, but can I do create a global trigger to all of my table in a database?

Comment: No, there are no global triggers (and they would be of little use if they would exists). If you want to, you can automatically create triggers for every table, see e.g. [Dynamically constructing MySQL Code for creating a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29110437/6248528).